# Invalid query on "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor"

Tags: windows, windows-10, wmi

My software (with admin priviledges) periodically performs the following query via WMI to know the status of the CPU:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
```

Suddenly (meaning after *months* where the result of `searcher.Get()` was always available) the command started sitting down and throwing an "Invalid query" Exception after a timeout. I cannot say what's changed in the machine before this happens.

I confirmed this error by testing it with tool `wbemtest`:

[image]

The error happens everytime, even after reboot. How can I debug it?

System is Windows 10 x64 IoT Enterprise v1607.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is explained in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19374.windows-performance-monitor-unable-to-add-these-counters.aspx).

Anyway, I still have not understood the reason why the counters may get corrupted. Any comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on a Windows 7 machine separate from a network and required to be kept around for various reasons.

At first I thought it was an admin thing (the program runs as a normal user) because system event viewer error 2011 hints at that.

However, it's fixed with this:

```
lodctr /r
```

I don't fully understand why, but this article was my source:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d574e10-17f5-4599-95d6-2492ede3cfef/wmi-query-from-net-application-cause-2011-error-event?forum=netfxbcl